# Is it possible to use two subclasses of PFUser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I use parse.com iOS framework in my app. My `User` object is subclass of standard parse `PFUser`. There are two distinct kind of users in my app: students and teachers. I'm tired of tons of `if (user.isTeacher) {...} else {...}` statements hanging all over my code and it looks like perfect target for polymorphism. The problem is: how parse framework would figure out whether it should return `Teacher` or `Student` subclass of `PFUser` on my query? Is there actually any way to have two subclasses of `PFUser` with parse? Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not. Have you at least give it a tried?

Comment: two subclasses sharing the same _User table?

Comment: did you figure it out, cannot even get a single PFUser subclass to work.

Comment: @DogCoffee Not enough time, unfortunately. To subclass PFUser just follow [this steps](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-defining/iOS)

Comment: PFUser is a different beast that PFObject, they work fine for me, just not PFUser. Maybe if I subclass PFUser, all the users references need to be for that new subclass.

Comment: @DogCoffee The only difference I've found in my PFUser subclass from other PFObject subclasses is it does not have `parseClassName` (because stock PFUser already implemented this method, and table is `_User`). I do treat all my users as that particular subclass.

Comment: did you need to register the PFUser subclass in the app delegate ?

Comment: @DogCoffee I do register every subclass in +load method of that particular subclass. You can do it in AppDelegate, but it's more convenient to have all stuff related to the subclass in one place si +load perfectly fits.

Comment: @AlexanderVasenin as of the new Parse 1.7.1 with Swift I had to register the subclass in the app delegate. The other method with in the class wont work.

Comment: @DogCoffee I've installed Parse 1.7.1 SDK today (yes, because of Xcode 6.3) and it works fine with registering in +load with Objective-C.

Comment: @DogCoffee There is one caveat with +load: runtime invokes it **only** for the class which implemented it, and **not** on it's subclasses, which is very confusing

Comment: @AlexanderVasenin do you know the way to implement the register subclass within the actual class like before ? I tried a couple of ways, but had to resort to the appDelegate. PS I'm loving swift 1.2!!

Comment: @DogCoffee I'm not in Swift yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **impossible**, at least with current version of Parse SDK (1.7.1), because `registerSubclass` method crashes for the second subclass with message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to register both
>   AnotherUser and User as the native PFObject subclass of _User. Cannot
>   determine the right class to use because neither inherits from the
>   other.'

Comment: Thanks, I just added a bool within the PFUser subclass to denote which is which as I have 2 clear users. Works fine.